# Stiffness matrix for FEA development

Tags: python, function, matrix, mef

I want to compute the stiffness matrix of the triangular element for plates using python

I was searching for code like CTRIA (by Nastran) but until now I didn't find it

I tried to compute it through some algorithms I found on the net but results were not satisfying